What is the translation of topline in French?
I read:

The topline of a song can be defined as the melody and words a vocalist sings—the elements that go on “top” of the instrumental track.

What is the translation of topline in French?  Google Translate and Linguee weren't helpful.

OK you read this and these ones were not helpful; now, what is it you have to translate and what is the outcome you're unhappy with?

Dans le milieu de la musique on dit "une topline".

@ninja米étoilé je n'y peux rien si le terme usité est le terme anglais. On peut toujours décider de s'inventer un mot bien de chez et inciter à son usage, mais en attendant le mot anglais prévaut.

@ninja米étoilé "What is the translation" n'est pas clair, est-ce qu'il veut le terme usité (la formulation semble partir du principe qu'une traduction existe, souvent ce n'est pas le cas), ou est-ce qu'il demande "quelle serait une bonne traduction de ce concept, s'il en existe pas déjà une ?".
